# How can I separate the column in my data file at a given string?

Tags: r

The col is named id and i need to separate them into two columns based on `_POS_`

```
id
*ID_131604_scaffold109166_Locus_191120_0_37.5_LINEAR_No_definition_line_found_POS_196
*ID_131604_scaffold109166_Locus_191120_0_37.5_LINEAR_No_definition_line_found_POS_204
*ID_131604_scaffold109166_Locus_191120_0_37.5_LINEAR_No_definition_line_found_POS_210
*ID_166920_C1460071_12.0_No_definition_line_found_POS_4529
*ID_167502_C1460265_46.0_No_definition_line_found_POS_720
*ID_167502_C1460265_46.0_No_definition_line_found_POS_727
*ID_167502_C1460265_46.0_No_definition_line_found_POS_734
*ID_167502_C1460265_46.0_No_definition_line_found_POS_2179
*ID_23929_C933331_63.0_No_definition_line_found_POS_121
*ID_23929_C933331_63.0_No_definition_line_found_POS_131
```

this is what i did

```
library(tidyr)
newdata <-seperate("AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv",id,into=c("id","POS"),sep="_POS_")
Error in seperate("AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv", id, into = c("id",  :
  could not find function "seperate"
 newdata <-separate("AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv",id,into=c("id","POS"),sep="_POS_")
```

> Error in UseMethod("separate_") :   no applicable method for
>   'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"

I am not sure how to proceed with this error.

Thanks for the comment : Here is the result ->

> str("AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv",)
>   chr "AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv"

@Elin Thanks for the suggestions. When i applied the comments this is what i got :

AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv
  as.data.frame(
"group/pasture/Saila/SNP_disco_AberdartXMatrix/AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv")
     newdata <- tidyr::separate(newdata, col =id, into= ("v1.1", "v1.2" ), sep = "*POS*")

> Error: unexpected ',' in "newdata <- tidyr::separate(newdata, col =id, into= ("v1.1","
>       newdata <- tidyr::separate(newdata, col =id, into= ("v1.1","v1.2" ), sep = "*POS*")
>
> Error: unexpected ',' in "newdata <- tidyr::separate(newdata, col =id, into= ("v1.1","
>        newdata <- tidyr::separate(newdata, col =id, into= c("v1.1", "v1.2"), sep = "*POS*")

Error in tidyr::separate(newdata, col = id, into = c("v1.1", "v1.2"),  :
  object 'newdata' not found

```
newdata <- tidyr::separate(AberdartXMatrixnewalldata, col =id, into= c("v1.1", "v1.2"), sep = "_POS_")
```

> Error in tidyr::separate(AberdartXMatrixnewalldata, col = id, into = c("v1.1",  :
>    object 'AberdartXMatrixnewalldata' not found

```
newdata <- tidyr::separate(AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv, col =id, into= c("v1.1", "v1.2"), sep = "_POS_")
```

> Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object 'id' not found

Comment: You can use tidyr::separate,  but because I am lazy, and you did't provide a reproducible example I can paste into R, I didn't provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks Harlan Nelson, this is what happened when i used separate        library(tidyr)
> newdata <-seperate("AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv",id,into=c("id","POS"),sep="_POS_")
Error in seperate("AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv", id, into = c("id",  :
  could not find function "seperate"
> newdata <-separate("AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv",id,into=c("id","POS"),sep="_POS_")
Error in UseMethod("separate_") :
  no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: Make sure you spell separate correctly.

Comment: Using `new_data <- separate(mydata, id, c("v1.1", "v1.2"), sep = "_POS_")` worked for me. If that doesn't work then there's nothing I can do until you provide a reproducible example

Comment: @sailajahvishwanathan, It seems your data is not a data.frame or data_frame. Please run a `str(your_object_which_contains_id)`, you will see kind of object it is. The function won't work if its not a data frame. OR best if do a `dput(head(your_object))`, and copy-paste the output in your question. It will tell other people your data as well. You should get a very good help.

Comment: @sailajahvishwanathan Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. As you can see people generally try to be helpful but also can be fussy since there are a lot of questions.  One thing that is very helpful is if you create your code in a way that people can just copy and paste it into R.  So in your case you didn't actually provide that because you should have a usable copy of your data or fake data similar to your data. It can just be 3 rows, that is fine. Also it really helps if you try to do formatting for readability.  Finally, on Stack Overflow they don't like please and thank you so I deleted.

Comment: @Elin Thanks for the suggestions. When i applied the comments this is what i got :

Comment: I tried to edit it but t's still kind of a mess to read.  So the first thing is please create the data frame and make sure you have a working data frame before trying anything else. Make sure you know its actual name and the name of the variable(s).  Copy the code from my answer below, specifically you need to use read.csv if you are working with a csv file.

Comment: library(tidyr)
>newdata <- read.csv("AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv", se=",",header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)>AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv <- as.data.frame("group/pasture/Saila/SNP_disco_AberdartXMatrix/AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv")
    newdata <- tidyr::separate(AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv, col =id, into= c("v1.1", "v1.2"), sep = "_POS_")
Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object 'id' not found
    > newdata <-separate(splitdata,id,into=c("id","POS"),sep="_POS_")
    Error in separate(splitdata, id, into = c("id", "POS"), sep = "_POS_") :
  object 'splitdata' not found

Comment: The results should be id Pos
*ID_131604_scaffold109166_Locus_191120_0_37.5_LINEAR_No_definition_line_found _POS_196
 *ID_131604_scaffold109166_Locus_191120_0_37.5_LINEAR_No_definition_line_found _POS_204
 *ID_131604_scaffold109166_Locus_191120_0_37.5_LINEAR_No_definition_line_found _POS_210
    *ID_166920_C1460071_12.0_No_definition_line_found _POS_4529

Comment: i tried this too

Answer (score 0):

Though you might be able to do it in one line, you'll be better off and understand what is happening better if you take things in a step by step way.

One issue you have in the code is that the tidyr separate function works on data frames but you are providing data in the form of a character vector, which is what that message is saying.

I'd suggest that first you create a data frame. Since it looks like you have a CSV file you can use the base R read.csv() function.

```
newdata <- read.csv("AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv", StringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If you have already created a data frame but that just happens to have this name that says it is a csv file and then id is a character variable you have isolated from the data frame, turn it back to a data frame.

```
AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv <- as.data.frame(AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv)
```

Please note that you may need to put a a path to the file.

Then you have options for doing the separation but I'd suggest installing tidyr and using its `separate()` function.

```
newdata <- tidyr::separate(newdata, col =id, into= ("v1.1", "v1.2" ), sep = "_POS_")
```

This preserves the id column but creates the two new columns.  Use the removed option if you want to drop it.

Comment: This isn't an answer. If you want to make a suggestion please add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this 
newdata <- tidyr::separate(AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv, col =objectid, into= c("id", "POS"), sep = "*POS*")
Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a list

> newdata <- tidyr::separate(AberdartXMatrixnewalldata.csv, col ="objectid", into= c("id", "POS"), sep = "*POS*")
>   Error: Strings must match column names. Unknown columns: objectid
>   head(newdata)
>                                                                                        id
>   1 *ID_131604_scaffold109166_Locus_191120_0_37.5_LINEAR_No_definition_line_found_POS_196
>   2 *ID_131604_scaffold109166_Locus_191120_0_37.5_LINEAR_No_definition_line_found_POS_204
>   3 *ID_131604_scaffold109166_Locus_191120_0_37.5_LINEAR_No_definition_line_found_POS_210
>   4                            *ID_166920_C1460071_12.0_No_definition_line_found_POS_4529
>   5                             *ID_167502_C1460265_46.0_No_definition_line_found_POS_720
>   6                             *ID_167502_C1460265_46.0_No_definition_line_found_POS_727
>     aa.count ab.count bb.count NC D1.10  B3.7 D2.15 Cross
>   1       43       17        0 33 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
>   2       56        3        0 34 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
>   3        1       25       33 34 FALSE FALSE  TRUE D2.15
>   4       48        5        4 36 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
>   5       30       17        0 46  TRUE FALSE FALSE D1.10
>   6       26       22        3 42  TRUE FALSE FALSE D1.10